# Trim off N samples from audio file using SoX / FFmpeg etc

Tags: ffmpeg, sox

Is there a way to trim off N samples from audio file using SoX / FFmpeg or the likes of?

Comment: Got it. Will do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [atrim filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atrim):

```
ffmpeg -i input -af atrim=start_sample=65614:end_sample=102400 output
```

- `start_sample` - The number of the first sample that should be output.
- `end_sample` - The number of the first sample that should be dropped.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what i needed. Is it possible to combine both of the parameters to get N-th sample with one FFmpeg invocation  (let's say 123456789)? I've tried ffmpeg -i input.wav -af atrim=start_sample=123456788 -af atrim=end_sample=123456789 output.wav

Comment: Cool! Thanks @LordNeckbeard

Answer (score 8):

Using SoX [trim](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) :

```
sox in.wav out.wav trim 0s 1000s
```

Trims first 1000 samples with 0 samples offset.

> *'s'* here means *'sample'*, not *'second'*. To trim by *'seconds'* you should
>   remove *'s'*

---

To trim specified range of sample(s):

```
sox in.wav out.wav trim 5000s 100s
```

Trims 100 samples, from 5000 to 5100 *(5000s - samples offset, 100s - number of samples to trim after offset)*

```
sox in.wav out.wav trim 123456788s 1s
```

Trims 123456789-nd sample *(123456788s - samples offset, 1s - number of samples to trim after offset)*